# Download SSL-certificate from a Public Site in a Linux Machine

Tags: apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux, httpd

***Require to download*** SSL-certificate from a open site in a linux machine.
https://fqsq02.six-group.com/sheldon.html 
Used Following command

```
root#>  openssl s_client -host fqsq02.six-group.com/sheldon.html -port 443 -prexit -showcerts
```

*I get following output:*

```
getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
connect:errno=111
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
```

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSSL `-host` parameter only takes a hostname, not part of a URL. If you run the following you won't get the error and immediately be returned to a prompt:

```
openssl s_client -host fqsq02.six-group.com -port 443 -showcerts </dev/null
```